Detector double slit experiment
I've been working on QM for long time, when coming back to the double slit experiment, I think I still fully understand it. When the detector is placed at either slit, the interference pattern disappears, I understand. But the detectors here are machines which can give us information of which slit the particle passes through. What I think is, if we place a  small bug (intelligent or not) which do not interact with the particle. Can this be a detector? No matter the small bug is intelligent or not, the information of the particle is there for it. So in this case, we don't see the interference pattern? Maybe this is a stupid question, but I didn't think about it before.

$\dots$ which do not interact with the particle. Can this be a detector? No interaction $\Rightarrow$ no detection.

but when I only place only one detector at one slit, if a particle is not detected, I know it passes through another, in this case, there's no interaction.

It's not always necessary, that the particle has to pass through one slit, in real life, that's just theory.

There is no such thing as "which state information" in quantum mechanics. As soon as we "detect" a quantum of energy (which means absorbing a quantum of energy), the original system has been destroyed. That the double slit experiment is even a quantum experiment is already complete nonsense. In a quantum experiment we will either find Planck's in some way OR we have to detect multi-quantum correlations (like in entanglement experiments). We aren't doing either in this case.

Surprisingly: there is no requirement that there be a which-path detector anywhere to eliminate (or not) interference in the Double Slit Experiment (DSE) with light (photons).  And it can be done with the exact same slit apparatus for both slits, so that the same total amount of light passes through regardless of which-slit is traversed.

You can place a polarizer in front of each slit (2 total polarizers), and orient them parallel relative to each other (0 degrees apart). If the loss of interference were strictly a result of photons passing through or otherwise interacting with the polarizers, then no interference pattern would result. But that is not what happens.  There IS the normal interference pattern.
So in actual experiments, it is the relative orientation of the 2 polarizers - and nothing else - that determines whether or not there is an interference pattern. If the polarizers are parallel, there IS the usual interference pattern. If the polarizers are perpendicular (90 degrees apart), there is NO interference pattern. Again, the total intensity of the resulting pattern is the same. See:
Young's double-slit experiment with single photons and quantum eraser
The general explanation is that if it is possible to learn the which slit information - even if it is not known - there will be NO interference. You could learn it by checking photon polarization. That polarization becomes a sort of marker, as explained in the paper.  But no observer needs to actually detect that polarization marker.
"Even if not actually measured, the mere possibility that an observer could determine which slit the photon passed through causes the interference pattern to switch to non-interference."
Also: If the polarizers were 45 degrees apart, for example, half of the photons will interfere with each other and half will not. The result is a mixing of the two patterns. By adjusting the relative angles, you can achieve whatever mixture of patterns you desire.  I.e. more or less of the interference pattern.
The overall explanation then comes back to this: As elements of the complete wave function pass through the left and right polarizers, they interfere to the extent that they are not orthogonal (perpendicular).  Clearly, if left one is V (vertical polarization) and the other is H (horizontal orientation) then they will not interfere at all, as they are mutually exclusive.  If they are both H or both V, there can be full interference.  The patterns will adjust accordingly.

Note: This explanation ignores the question of whether there is an "interaction" of some type, as there clearly is no single spot to point to where an interaction occurs.  Any interaction is still a result of the full quantum setup (the "context").

Very interesting, but I think that the experiment can be interpreted differently. The two polarisers always act coherently and the state of a single photon after them is always a coherent superposition of two states:$\Psi =\sum_{i=1}^2|\lambda_i\rangle|\psi_i\rangle$ with generally different polarisations $\lambda_i$. The screen is not able to detect the polarisation. It is an observable of the form $O=I\otimes X$. Therefore $\langle \Psi|O\Psi\rangle = \sum_{i,j} \langle\lambda_i|\lambda_j\rangle \langle \psi_i|X\psi_j\rangle$.

If the polarisations are orthogonal, the interference terms disappear and the state can be replaced for a corresponding mixture. Otherwise they play a role. Here there is no measurement, just a transformation of states (a filter). In my view it is disputable to assert that the (unknown ) information is responsible for the distruction of the interference pattern. I should read the paper into the details however, mine is just a superficial impression.

@ValterMoretti With due respect: Yes, there are several ways to interpret this. What can't be debated is that ideally the interference pattern can be dialed from 0 to 100%  based ONLY on the relative angles. No which-slit detector need be placed at the screen, but this is possible too. Also: an extra polarizer can be inserted so the which-slit marker attribute is "erased". Regardless, there's no requirement for an observer and the only requirement is the "possibility" of learning the unknown which-slit info. And no interaction occurs at the polarized slit alone, as it is present in all cases.

@ValterMoretti The Harvard paper is more of a 1st year support document for the DSE, not a rigorous treatment. Further considerations are the fact that the laser light source is already polarized in this apparatus, as polarizers are assigned to each slit one can say the loss in interference is simply due to the inability of the polarizer orthogonal to the source that effectively makes this a single slit.

Thank you for both comments. I am not an experimentalist and I have just a superficial impression on this experiment.

@PhysicsDave In the cited experiment (I.B), the laser source is clearly labeled as being 45 degrees relative to H> and V>.  Of course it doesn’t correspond to a single slit, that would defeat the purpose. See figures 8 and 9.

@DrChinese  Oops ... yes you are correct ... I see that condition now.  My explanation is if an excited source electron's disturbance/effect on the EM field can  see both slits then the field can interfere and guide the eventual photon on the allowed paths, i.e. interference.  This is similar to your "complete wave function" passing thru 2 slits.  This is similar to pilot wave or pre wave as suggested in many papers as an explanation for the DSE.

This is a just trivial mistake. Orthogonal states have absolutely nothing to do with detection. Orthogonal states are unitary, detection is not.
